# Visualizing Meshcat Trajectory

Tags: drake

Currently I have a Multibody plant and Scenegraph created in the following way:

```
    builder = DiagramBuilder() 
    plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder=builder, time_step=0)
    parser = Parser(plant)
    ConfigureParser(parser)
    parser.AddModelsFromString(minigolf_urdf, 'urdf')
    plant.Finalize()

    builder.ExportInput(plant.get_actuation_input_port(), "actuation")
    diagram = builder.Build()
    diagram_context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
    plant_context = scene_graph.GetMyContextFromRoot(diagram_context)
    dircol = DirectCollocation(
        diagram,
        diagram_context,
        num_time_samples=41,
        minimum_timestep=0.1,
        maximum_timestep=1
    )
```

I am trying to visualize the trajectory with the following:

```
    trajectory = dircol.ReconstructStateTrajectory(result)
    builder = DiagramBuilder()
    source = builder.AddSystem(TrajectorySource(trajectory))
    builder.AddSystem(scene_graph)
    pos_to_pose = builder.AddSystem(
        MultibodyPositionToGeometryPose(plant, input_multibody_state=True)
    )
    builder.Connect(source.get_output_port(0), pos_to_pose.get_input_port())
    builder.Connect(
        pos_to_pose.get_output_port(),
        scene_graph.get_source_pose_port(plant.get_source_id()),
    )

    visualizer = builder.AddSystem(
        PlanarSceneGraphVisualizer(
            scene_graph, xlim=[-4, 4], ylim=[-2, 2], show=False
        )
    )
    builder.Connect(
        scene_graph.get_query_output_port(), visualizer.get_input_port(0)
    )
```

This used to work when I created the plant and scenegraph separately and attached them, but now it gets an error saying

```
RuntimeError: C++ object must be owned by pybind11 when attempting to release to C++
```

on the line builder.AddSystem(scene_graph). Is there any other way to visualize this trajectory?

Answer (score 0):

As it stands today in Drake, a System can only be added to at most one Diagram.  The reason the second `builder.AddSystem(scene_graph)` fails is because the `scene_graph` is already associated with the DirectCollocation's Diagram.

I'm not able to test right now, but I believe that copying (cloning) the `scene_graph` would work:

```py
    trajectory = dircol.ReconstructStateTrajectory(result)
    builder = DiagramBuilder()
    source = builder.AddSystem(TrajectorySource(trajectory))
    scene_graph2 = scene_graph.Clone()
    builder.AddSystem(scene_graph2)
```

Then be sure to refer to `scene_graph2` instead of `scene_graph` in the remaining visualization code.

Also note that `copy.copy(scene_graph)` and `scene_graph.Clone()` are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I tried adding that but now the line
```OutputPort: The Context given as an argument was not created for this OutputPort[0] (query) of System ::_::scene_graph (SceneGraph<double>)
``` gives an error saying:
```OutputPort: The Context given as an argument was not created for this OutputPort[0] (query) of System ::_::scene_graph (SceneGraph<double>)```
Does this mean I need the original scene_graph to use my trajectory?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that the simplest workflow would be to start up an entirely new diagram (with a new MultibodyPlant / SceneGraph which gets parsed from disk again) for your visualization; following, for instance, the cart-pole example in [this notebook](https://deepnote.com/workspace/Underactuated-2ed1518a-973b-4145-bd62-1768b49956a8/project/10-Trajectory-Optimization-05031f8c-3586-4b47-be79-7f4893cf2f9d/notebook/dircol-6ed92d642b4e42e6802e3e851e516596) which I presume you started from.  The only data that you would need to preserve from the first version is the actual trajectory.

The difference in your case is that you needed to make the diagram for the trajectory optimization; and I got away in that cart-pole example without doing that.

Approximate (untested) code:

```
def trajopt():
  builder = DiagramBuilder()
  plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder=builder, time_step=0)
  parser = Parser(plant)
  ConfigureParser(parser)
  parser.AddModelsFromString(minigolf_urdf, 'urdf')
  plant.Finalize()

  builder.ExportInput(plant.get_actuation_input_port(), "actuation")
  diagram = builder.Build()
  diagram_context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
  plant_context = scene_graph.GetMyContextFromRoot(diagram_context)
  dircol = DirectCollocation(
      diagram,
      diagram_context,
      num_time_samples=41,
      minimum_timestep=0.1,
      maximum_timestep=1
  )
  ...
  return dircol.ReconstructStateTrajectory(result)

traj = trajopt()
builder = DiagramBuilder()
plant = MultibodyPlant(time_step=0.0)
scene_graph = SceneGraph()
plant.RegisterAsSourceForSceneGraph(scene_graph)
parser = Parser(plant)
ConfigureParser(parser)
parser.AddModelsFromUrl(minigolf_urdf...)
plant.Finalize()

source = builder.AddSystem(TrajectorySource(x_trajectory))
builder.AddSystem(scene_graph)
pos_to_pose = builder.AddSystem(
  MultibodyPositionToGeometryPose(plant, input_multibody_state=True)
)
builder.Connect(source.get_output_port(0), pos_to_pose.get_input_port())
builder.Connect(
  pos_to_pose.get_output_port(),
  scene_graph.get_source_pose_port(plant.get_source_id()),
)

visualizer = builder.AddSystem(
 PlanarSceneGraphVisualizer(
    scene_graph, xlim=[-2, 2], ylim=[-1.25, 2], show=False)
 )
builder.Connect(
  scene_graph.get_query_output_port(), visualizer.get_input_port(0)
)
simulator = Simulator(builder.Build())
...
```